# Pull an element out of the scope of hover()

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu bar with elements that animate to 50% opacity on hover.

When the hover effect is enabled, an overlay appears that says "CLICK TO EDIT". However, this overlay (as it falls within the animated `div`), is also translucent.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/3/

How can I go about getting the content within `.click-to-edit` to not animate, keeping it at 100% opacity? Do I need to pull them out of the scope of `hover()`, or adjust their CSS?

JQuery:

```
$(".list-group-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.5"
    }, 250);
    $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "block");
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 250);
    $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "none");
});
```

CSS:

```
.click-to-edit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.
                <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                Brunch Bushwick pop-up ennui Kickstarter.  Yr crucifix scenester, Shoreditch taxidermy art party flannel Odd Future.
                <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to keep opacity of child different from that of its parent. Parent's opacity will affect the child element. Better way is to have a separate div which contain the text and set opacity on it.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
        <div class="list-group"> <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                <div class="text">Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.</div>
                <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
 <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                <div class="text">Brunch Bushwick pop-up ennui Kickstarter.  Yr crucifix scenester, Shoreditch taxidermy art party flannel Odd Future.</div>
                <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".list-group-item").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".text").stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.5"
    }, 250);
    $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "block");
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".text").animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, 250);
    $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "none");
});
```

Here, the text part is wrapped inside `.text` div

**A Pure CSS solution:**

**Html**:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
        <div class="list-group"> <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                <div class="text">Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.</div>
                <div class="click-to-edit">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
 <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                <div class="text">Brunch Bushwick pop-up ennui Kickstarter.  Yr crucifix scenester, Shoreditch taxidermy art party flannel Odd Future.</div>
                <div class="click-to-edit">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.click-to-edit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.list-group-item:hover .text {
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all 400ms ease-in-out; //modify it according to your choice.
}
.list-group-item:hover .click-to-edit {
    display:block;
}
.click-to-edit {
    display:none;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/9/

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is inherited. My rule of thumb always use `background-color: rgba`

EDIT:

*Opacity affects all other child elements of the styled containing element*

[See updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-group-container"> 
       <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.</a>
       <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none"><span>CLICK TO EDIT</span></div>
</div>
<div class="list-group-container"> 
       <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.</a>
       <div class="click-to-edit" style="display:none"><span>CLICK TO EDIT</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-group-container {
   position: relative;
}
.click-to-edit {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   font-weight: 700;
   text-align: center;
}

.click-to-edit span {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".list-group-container").hover(function () {
     $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "block");
}, function () {
     $(this).find(".click-to-edit").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: _“Opacity is inherited”_ – no, it is not; not in the sense CSS uses the term “inheritance”. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color-3/#opacity: _“Inherited: no”_

Comment: "Opacity affects all other child elements". Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using jquery also like this.[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3jeezjrb/10/)

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:15px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                Put a bird on it meditation Williamsburg distillery banh mi disrupt. Artisan PBR&amp;B synth sustainable photo booth.
                <div class="click-to-edit">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
            <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                Brunch Bushwick pop-up ennui Kickstarter.  Yr crucifix scenester, Shoreditch taxidermy art party flannel Odd Future.
                <div class="click-to-edit">CLICK TO EDIT</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.click-to-edit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:2
}

.list-group a:hover .click-to-edit{display:block}
.list-group a{position:relative;}
```